# initialization of array using vector in cpp

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

```
vector< vector<int> > pairSum(vector<int> &arr, int s){
    int n = arr.size();
    // Used to store result.
    vector< vector<int> > ans;
        
    // Checking sum for every element.
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for(int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if(arr[i] + arr[j] == s) {
                vector<int> pair(2);
                pair[0] = arr[i];
                pair[1] = arr[j];
                ans.push_back(pair);
            }`enter code here`
        }
    }

    // Used to store final sorted result.
    vector<vector<int> > res(ans.size(),vector<int>(2,0));
    for(int i = 0; i < ans.size(); i++) {
        int a = ans[i][0], b = ans[i][1];

        res[i][0] = min(a, b);
        res[i][1] = max(a, b);
    }
    sort(res.begin(),res.end());  
    return}
```

what is the need of this line in code
`vector<vector<int> > res(ans.size(),vector<int>(2,0));`
what is the processing of this line
I think it will intialise new vector of type vector but I want to know on what basis and how the vector is initialised?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector

Comment: There are no arrays in this code. `vector<T> (size, element)` is a vector containing `size` copies of `element`, regardless of what type `T` is.

Comment: Note that a more up-to-date solution would use `std::vector<std::array<int, 2>>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break this into parts:

```
vector<vector<int>> res
```

Initializes a vector `res`, of which every element is a vector of integers

```
(ans.size(), vector<int>(2, 0))
```

To understand this part it is better to visualize `vector<vector<int>>` as a 2D array:

```
      +--------------------------------------------+
      |                                            |
+---+---+ <----+                                   |
| 0 | 0 |      |                                   |
+---+---+      |                                   |
| 0 | 0 |      |                                   |
+---+---+      |                                   |
| 0 | 0 |  ans.size() <---------------------------------+
+---+---+      |                                   |    |
| 0 | 0 |      |                                   |    |
+---+---+      |                                   |    |
| 0 | 0 |      |                                   |    |
+---+---+ <----+                                   |    |
|-- 2 --|                                          |    |
    |                                              |    |
    +-------------------------------------------+  |    |
                                                |  |    |
vector<vector<int>> res(ans.size(), vector<int>(2, 0))  |
                            |                           |
                            +---------------------------+
```

So `ans.size()` is the length of the outer vector, `2` is the length of each of the inner vectors, and `0` is the value to which each element of the inner vectors will be initialized.

Comment: thank you very much ,I have completely understood